# Como modificar el footer para que no tape el contenido de una tabla responsive de bootstrap?

Tags: angular, bootstrap, footer

estoy realizando una app sencilla con angular y bootstrap, realice un componente footer y lo mando a llamar en el **app.html** de la siguiente manera: `<app-footer></app-footer>`  para que asi todos los componentes lo tengan ya agregado.

mi footer. html es el siguiente de ejemplo:

```html
<footer class="footer" id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content has-text-centered text-muted">
            <P>
                Derechos reservados. Miguel Hidalgo centro historioc 44
            </P>
        </div>

    </div>
</footer>
```

y el footer.css

```html
.text-muted{
    color: black;
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Ahora, tengo mi componente consulta tareas, en la cual tengo dos tablas responsivas de la siguiente manera:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu Principal</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
    Consulta de tareas
</p>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">tarea</th>
                    <th scope="col">descripcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">funcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">nivel</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Clasificacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            EJEMPLO OTRA TABLA RESPONSIVA
        </p>
        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">tarea</th>
                    <th scope="col">descripcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">funcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">nivel</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Clasificacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

y lo que pasa es que cuando agrego el componente footer, las tablas salen asi, el footer tapa el contenido de la tabla de hasta abajo y no sale el scroll como en la tabla de arriba
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y si quito el footer, si sale bien el contenido de la 2da tabla
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

que estoy haciendo mal con mi footer?
que le debo modificar?

Answer (score 2):

Hola mi solucion para tu problema fue agregarle un padding bottom al body.

[image: Aqui el ejemplo de como se vería]

```css
body
{
    padding-bottom: 10%;
}

.text-muted{
    color: black;
}

.footer{
    position: fixed;
    display: inline-block;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Menu Principal</a>
    </div>
</nav>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
    Consulta de tareas
</p>
<br>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">

        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">tarea</th>
                    <th scope="col">descripcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">funcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">nivel</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Clasificacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>
        <br>
        <br>
        <p style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold;">
            EJEMPLO OTRA TABLA RESPONSIVA
        </p>
        <table class="table table-striped table-responsive">
            <thead style="background-color: blueviolet;">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">id</th>
                    <th scope="col">tarea</th>
                    <th scope="col">descripcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">funcion</th>
                    <th scope="col">nivel</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo</th>
                    <th scope="col">Clasificacion</th>
                    <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>Mark</td>
                    <td>Otto</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                    <td>@mdo</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

    <footer class="footer" id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="content has-text-centered text-muted">
                <P>
                    Derechos reservados. Miguel Hidalgo centro historioc 44
                </P>
            </div>

        </div>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Es mejor usar las [utilidades propias de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/utilities/spacing/), hacen lo mismo, pero sin necesidad de duplicar CSS